# Is There an Easy Way to Copy the Text of SharePoint Designer Workflows?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I have rather complicated SharePoint Designer Workflows, and I would like to document my code. I tried adding using the "Add Comment" action in SPD, but it just makes the whole thing messy and unreadable.

I would like an easy way to get the text of my workflows and put it into a document where I can explain what is happening and why.

For instance, here is an example of a workflow:

If Current Item: Title contains "Text"
   Set Variable:Email? to "No"

It would be nice to be able to somehow copy this format from SharePoint designer without typing everything out myself. I am not sure it is possible, but it is worth checking.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, I am also not aware of any add-ons that will accomplish this.  You can access the workflow file (will have a .xaml extension) via SharePoint Designer. You can export this and open it in notepad or any editor that supports XML files.  You can probably grab some of this from there, but you will still end up modifying the text output. You dont want to do this with the live file, and errant marks in here will kill your workflow.

My typical approach is to model it in Visio or MindMapper and then keep it updated as I'm working on the workflow.  The diagram then serves as my documentation of the process.

Answer (score 1):

Export the Xoml file and edit it using Visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

There is an "Export to Visio" option available for SPD workflow to export as a flow diagram if you want an alternate to text.

Thanks,
Venkat Konjeti

Answer (score 0):

You can in SharePoint Designer 2013 - have you tried copy/pasting your steps? It gets most information, enough for documentation. It doesn't get the details of action settings or the details of emails, but it gives you the basic structure.

Since this is an old question the OP might not be around, or on SPD 2013, but for those that are...